QGIS Script - Use the results of a child algorithm
I want to create a script that runs native:pointsalonglines as a child algorithm and then does some other things with the results.
But the moment I use getFeatures() in the results of the child algorithm, QGIS totally crashes. How can I use the generated points without crashing QGIS?
The test code is pretty simple:
   def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        #run child algorithm
        pointsResult = processing.run(
            "native:pointsalonglines", 
            {
                'INPUT': parameters['INPUT'],
                'DISTANCE':5,
                'START_OFFSET':0,
                'END_OFFSET':0,
                'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
            }, 
            is_child_algorithm=True, 
            context = context, 
            feedback = feedback
        )
        
        #gets the result of the child algorithm as a layer
        pointsLayer = context.getMapLayer(pointsResult['OUTPUT'])
        
        #if the code ends here, all is ok   
        #I can even take some basic information like pointsLayer.featureCount()
       

        #but whenever I get the features, QGIS will crash at the end of the script
        pointFeatures = list(pointsLayer.getFeatures()) #PROBLEM 

        #I want to do things with the generated features here
        #But first I need to access the features... 
       
        return {'OUTPUT': 10}

As for this test code, the parameters are set as follows:
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    
        #input
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                'INPUT',
                self.tr('Line input'),
                types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine]
            )
        )
        
        # Output 
        self.addOutput(
            QgsProcessingOutputNumber(
                'OUTPUT',
                self.tr('A number')
            )
        )


Hard to say, that alone should not cause a crash. Maybe you do something after that which is not thread safe. I added an answer to your other question.

@BenW ,  I created this super empty test code (which is exactly what I posted here), where I do absolutely nothing, just to test out this possibility. The problem is getFeatures().

Honestly, I can't reproduce your problem! Try just closing and reopening QGIS!

I have no idea why, but using the approach in your other answer solves this. Taking the features with a request and iterating in a for. (As for restarting, every crash was a restart)

That's strange- I also tested a very simple algorithm structure including the line you use here and I did not get any crashes. Maybe you do need to try a new QGIS profile (as was suggested by another user on your question about empty projects list).

I already have a new profile (LOL), it did solve a few things. But thank you very much, I'll just keep this request approach and avoid list.

I came up with what I'll consider good practices from now on.
Although the documentation says I should raise QgsProcessingException, at least in my weird behaved QGIS, any exception makes it unstable, crashing sooner or later. Two patterns I was able to recognize:

run script, exception thrown and displayed in the log normally, all seems fine, fix code, run again, everything crashes.
run script, exception thrown and displayed normally, all seems fine, try edit the code, everything crashes during edit.

So, in order to completely avoid many crashes, there are two things:

Wrap the whole code in a try except block, and do NOT raise any exception. Use feedback.reportError(traceback.format_exc(), True) instead.
Read the result layers using QgsFeatureRequest, retrieve something from the features during enumeration instead of making a plain list of features, and delete the enumerator as soon as possible (also delete the layer as soon as possible)

So, for the first practice:
import traceback

...
...

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    try:
        #all the code here
        return {'OUTPUT': usuallyALayerIdAsString}
    except:
        feedback.reportError(traceback.format_exc(), True)
        return {}

And for the second practice, I created a method to retrieve the geometries using a request:
    def readLayerGeometries(self, layer, *fieldNames):

        request = QgsFeatureRequest().setSubsetOfAttributes(fieldNames, layer.fields())
        
        #geometries returned as (i, geometry, *fields)
        geometries = []
        iterator = layer.getFeatures(request)
        for i, feature in enumerate(iterator):
            geometries.append(
                (
                    i,
                    feature.geometry(), 
                    *[feature[fieldName] for fieldName in fieldNames]
                ) 
            )
        del iterator 
        
        return geometries

In the processing code, something like:

pointsLayer = context.getMapLayer(pointsResult['OUTPUT'])

pointGeometries = self.readLayerGeometries(pointsLayer, 'Field1', 'Field2', ...)

del pointsLayer

for i, geometry, field1Value, field2Value, ... in pointGeometries:
    #go for it

Using the results in MANY child processes
Finally, one of my applications needed to get every single feature from a result and run a child process (if run for all at once, the result is different from expected).
Here, one important catch (besides the previous ones) is to clear the stored layers once in a while. The layer storage accumulates and the code speed keeps getting slower as it advances. To avoid it, we need to remove the temporary layers from the storage.
This is how I achieved to use single features from a processing result (it's probably a good idea to wrap everything in a try block as shown before):
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        
        
        #get inputs
        ...
        
        
        feedback.setProgressText('Creating buffers')
        
        
        #generate buffer
        bufferResult = processing.run(
            "native:buffer", 
            {
                'INPUT':parameters['INPUT'],
                'DISTANCE':width,
                'SEGMENTS':5,
                'END_CAP_STYLE':1,
                'JOIN_STYLE':0,
                'MITER_LIMIT':2,
                'DISSOLVE':False,
                'OUTPUT':'memory:' #the results should not be saved
            }, 
            is_child_algorithm=True, 
            context=context,
            feedback=feedback
        )
        
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}
        
        #getting the content of the results    
        bufferLayer = context.getMapLayer(bufferResult['OUTPUT'])
        bufferLayerId = bufferLayer.id()
        bufferCount = bufferLayer.featureCount()
        

        allBufferGeometries = self.readLayerGeometries( #see code above
            bufferLayer, 
            'Field_1',
            'Field_2'
        )
        
        
        feedback.setProgressText('Creating clips')

        #I'll store here the ids of each clip layer that will be generated below
        allClipIds = [] 
        
        #create clips para for each buffer
        for i, bufferGeometry, fieldVal1, fieldVal2 in bufferGeometries:
    
    
            #important stuff for keeping a good speed
            if i % 50 == 0: #every 50 buffers processed ....

                feedback.setProgress(100 * (i+1) / float(bufferCount)) #progress bar
                
                layerStore = context.temporaryLayerStore() #here the memory layers are stored
                layerMap = layerStore.mapLayers() #these are the layers by id

                #these layers accumulate and make the code grow slower
                #we need to remove them                 
                for id in allClipIds: 
                    if id in layerMap:
                        layerStore.removeMapLayer(id)
                allClipIds = []
                
                
            #as for using a single buffer in the follow processing,
            #we erase the features in the resulting buffer layer
            bufferLayer.startEditing()
            bufferLayer.dataProvider().truncate()  #clear features
             
            #creating a single buffer feature from the previous result
            selectedBufferFeature = QgsFeature()
            selectedBufferFeature.setAttributes([fieldVal1, fieldVal2])
            selectedBufferFeature.setGeometry(bufferGeometry)
            
            #add the new feature to the result table itself
            bufferLayer.addFeature(selectedBufferFeature)
            bufferLayer.commitChanges()
            
            
            # perform clips with the single buffer 
            intersectResult = processing.run(
                "native:clip", 
                {
                    'INPUT':parameters['INPUT_TO_CLIP'],
                    'OVERLAY':bufferLayerId, #we use the id of the buffer layer
                    'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
                },
                is_child_algorithm = True, 
                context = context 
                #feedback = feedback #don't want log messages for every single clip 
            )
            
            #get clip results 
            intersectLayer = context.getMapLayer(intersectResult['OUTPUT'])
            intersectLayerId = intersectLayer.id()
            allClipIds.append(intersectLayerId) #store the id to remove later    
            
            #do what you need with the clips  
            #prefer to get them with self.readLayerGeometries(...)
            #add each resulting feature in a sink
            
            del intersectLayer
                
            if feedback.isCanceled():
                del bufferLayer
                return {}
                
        del bufferLayer
        
        #more code
        
        return {'OUTPUT': someIdThatIsNotInThisCode}    

